# python .format thousands separator in specified field width

Tags: python, format

in python 2.7 the following two expressions work:

```
'{:8}'.format(3333)
'{:,}'.format(3333)
```

but

```
'{:,8}.format(3333)
```

gives the very specific error message "Cannot specify ',' with '8'".

As far as I can tell the format that doesn't work is consistent with Format Specification Mini-Language. Logically the format doesn't seem to be asking for an inconsistent or very difficult thing to create.

There are obvious workarounds such as

```
'{:>8}'.format('{:,}'.format(3333))
```

but the seemingly easily-removed restriction seems unpythonic.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the obvious:

```
>>> '{:8,}'.format(3333)
'   3,333'
```

Grouping option comes *after* width in the [format spec mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).